# Evaluate one query against a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a couple loosely related tables. I need to evaluate a count against another count.

Query 1 is

```
SELECT
    COUNT(n.Caption) AS Interfaces
FROM NodesData n
LEFT JOIN [Interfaces] i ON i.NodeID = n.NodeID
GROUP BY n.Caption
```

Query 2 is

```
SELECT
    COUNT(n.Caption) AS Volumes
FROM NodesData n
LEFT JOIN [Volumes] v ON v.NodeID = n.NodeID
GROUP BY n.Caption
```

Ideally, I need to output a table that has 2 columns. The second column being the challenging one.

n.Caption | (If query1>query2 then query1 Else query2)

I'm just not sure how to evaluate multiple rows against each other. Here is a top 5 of each table. Which ever count is higher, that's the one that needs to be resulted in my query.

[image: Here is]

Comment: so you want to compare each and every row of both the results right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See whether this works;

```
Select Caption, 
    Case When Interfaces > Volumes then Interfaces Else Volumes End as VorI
From
(
    SELECT
        ni.Caption, COUNT(ni.Caption) AS Interfaces, COUNT(nv.Caption) AS Volumes
    FROM NodesData ni
    inner join NodesData nv on ni.NodeID = nv.NodeID
    LEFT JOIN [Interfaces] i ON i.NodeID = ni.NodeID
    LEFT JOIN [Volumes] v ON v.NodeID = nv.NodeID
    GROUP BY ni.Caption
) Q
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use outer apply:

```
SELECT n.Caption, SUM(i.cnt) AS Interfaces, SUM(v.cnt) as Volumes
FROM NodesData n
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM [Interfaces] i 
    WHERE i.NodeID = n.NodeID
) i
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM [Volumes] v 
    WHERE v.NodeID = n.NodeID
) v
GROUP BY n.Caption;
```

If you need the largest of the two values, you can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT n.Caption,
    (CASE WHEN SUM(i.cnt) > COALESCE(SUM(v.CNT), 0) THEN SUM(i.CNT)
    ELSE SUM(v.cnt) END) as the_bigger_one
```